# Recursively filter a multidimensional array and collect elements with a minimum string length

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, filtering, flatten

I have an array like this:

```
[
    [
        'key1' => 'hello im a text',
        'key2' => true,
        'key3' => '><><',
    ],
    [
        [
            'key1' => 'hello another text',
            'key2' => 'im a text too',
            'key3' => false,
        ],
        [
            'key1' = ')(&#',
        ],
    ],
    [
        'key1' => 'and so on',
    ]
]
```

How can I extract values which with a string length of 5 or more and populate a flat array?

Desired result:

```
[
    1 => 'hello im a text',
    2 => 'hello another text',
    3 => 'im a text too',
    4 => 'and so on',
]
```

Heres what I've done:

```
$found = array();
function search_text($item, $key)
{
    global $found;
    if (strlen($item) > 5)
    {
        $found[] = $item;
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($array, 'search_text');
var_dump($found);
```

but somehow it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something similar to this:

```
function array_simplify($array, $newarray=array()) { //default of $newarray to be empty, so now it is not a required parameter
    foreach ($array as $i) { 
        if (is_array($i)) { //if it is an array, we need to handle differently
            $newarray = array_simplify($i, $newarray); // recursively calls the same function, since the function only appends to $newarray, doesn't reset it
            continue; // goes to the next value in the loop, we know it isn't a string
        }
        if (is_string($i) && strlen($i)>5) { // so we want it in the one dimensional array
            $newarray[] = $i; //append the value to $newarray
        }
    }
    return $newarray; // passes the new array back - thus also updating $newarray after the recursive call
}
```

My note: I haven't tested this, if there's bugs, please tell me and I'll try to fix them.

Comment: i mean filtering arrays and make a new array that is one dimensional array value if (strlen($item) > 5) in the multidimensional old array

Comment: So it also has to be a string then? Assuming so, I have added the relevant if clause.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work,

as condition i've used

```
if(is_string($son))
```

in order to get some results, you can adjust it as you prefer

```
$input = <your input array>;
$output = array();

foreach($input AS $object)
{
    search_text($object,$output);
}

var_dump($output);

function search_text($object, &$output)
{
    foreach($object AS $son)
    {
        if(is_object($son))
        {
            search_text($son, $output);
        }
        else
        {
            if(is_string($son))
            {
                $output[] = $son;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Description:

`search_text` gets 2 parameters: the `$object` and the resulting array `$output`.

It checks foreach object's property if it is an object or not.

If it is then that object needs to be checked itself,

otherwise `search_text` checks if the input is a string, if it is the it is stored into the `$output` array