# Filter recursive array and only remove NULL value

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I want to remove all null or blank value but not false and 0 value from recursive array.

```
function isNotNull($val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        $ret = array_filter($val, 'isNotNull');
        return $ret;
    } else {
        return (!is_null($val) && $val !== '');
   }

}
```

$arr = array_filter($arr, 'isNotNull');

Input:

```
$arr = array(
"stringKey" => "Abc",
"boolKey" => false,
"zeroKey" => 0,
"blankKey" => '',
"newArr" => array(
    "stringKey2"=>"Abc2", 
    "boolKey2"=>false, 
    "zeroKey2" => 0, 
    "blankKey2"=>"", 
    "blankArr" => array()
    )
);
```

This give output:

```
Array
(
    [stringKey] => Abc
    [boolKey] => 
    [zeroKey] => 0
    [newArr] => Array
        (
            [stringKey2] => Abc2
            [boolKey2] => 
            [zeroKey2] => 0
            [blankKey2] => 
            [blankArr] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

But i want to bellow output:

```
 Array
(
    [stringKey] => Abc
    [boolKey] => 
    [zeroKey] => 0
    [newArr] => Array
        (
            [stringKey2] => Abc2
            [boolKey2] => 
            [zeroKey2] => 0
        )
)
```

I used array_filter with callback function but it only filter simple array not multidimensional array. I don't want to use loop.

Comment: you call callback function from inside of callback function. why?

Comment: @diavolic bcz i want to filter multidimension array

Comment: you use is_null() function, but it works only when you set variable to NULL. To get needed result use empty()

Comment: empty() remove false or 0 values but i don't want to remove 0 or false value

Comment: Relevant: [Recursively filter a multidimensional array and collect elements with a minimum string length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10940877/2943403) and [How to remove empty entries of an array recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7696548/2943403)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could combine `array_map` and `array_filter` in an recursive called function. Something like this could work for you.

```
function filterNotNull($array) {
    $array = array_map(function($item) {
        return is_array($item) ? filterNotNull($item) : $item;
    }, $array);
    return array_filter($array, function($item) {
        return $item !== "" && $item !== null && (!is_array($item) || count($item) > 0);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't need to reinvent recursion yourself. You can use [`RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator.php):

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr),
        function ($value) {
            return $value !== null && $value !== '';
        }
    )
);

$result = iterator_to_array($iterator);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e86706f3b621ca09e0a4c9c5ed60fa86a8fad363).

You should try to use as much stuff from **[Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)**  as you can.

**UPDATE:**
**As it is stated in the comments, the solution with iterator not actually suits for this purpose.**

In the comments to the [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) function you can find the implementation of [`walk_recursive_remove`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php#114574) function:

```
function walk_recursive_remove (array $array, callable $callback) { 
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) { 
        if (is_array($v)) { 
            $array[$k] = walk_recursive_remove($v, $callback); 
        } else { 
            if ($callback($v, $k)) { 
                unset($array[$k]); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    return $array; 
}
```

This generalized version of recursion function takes criteria in the form of callback. Having this function you can remove empty elements like this:

```
$result = walk_recursive_remove($arr, function ($value) {
    return $value === null || $value === '';
});
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e57ab0140a2fcdb1e01f72343094cf3fe2205118).

Comment: @Philipp, yes, my bad. I have updated my answer. Thank you for pointing this.

Comment: Nice solution. Is there a way to let it remove sub-arrays with a certain key instead of a value?

Comment: @DønerM., thank you. `$key` is passed as a second parameter to the callback. So you can use it to match criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Here you require filtering of an array for `empty string`. In this code below you can add no of checks to filter it recursively. Hope it will work fine.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/778533)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
//Using more complexed sample array for filter it.
$arr = array(
    "stringKey" => "Abc",
    "boolKey" => false,
    "zeroKey" => 0,
    "blankKey" => '',
    "newArr" => array(
        "stringKey2" => "Abc2",
        "boolKey2" => false,
        "zeroKey2" => 0,
        "blankKey2" => "",
        "blankArr" => array(
            "blankString"=>"",
            "zeroKey"=>0,
            "blankArr3"=>array()
        )
    )
);

$result=recursiveFilter($arr);
print_r($result);


function recursiveFilter($value)
{
    foreach ($value as $key => $value1)
    {
        if ($value1 === "")  unset($value[$key]);//you can add no. of conditions here.
        else if (is_array($value1)) $value[$key] = recursiveFilter($value1);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [stringKey] => Abc
    [boolKey] => 
    [zeroKey] => 0
    [newArr] => Array
        (
            [stringKey2] => Abc2
            [boolKey2] => 
            [zeroKey2] => 0
            [blankArr] => Array
                (
                    [zeroKey] => 0
                    [blankArr3] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```